# Delegated events : selector of many elements

Tags: jquery

I want to handle 2 elements in a delegated events manner :

```
$("#pagination_container").on("click", ".image-container", function() {
     var c = $("#article_"+$(this).attr("data-pk"));
     var q = $("#qtecmd_"+$(this).attr("data-pk"));
     if (c.is(":checked")) {
         c.prop("checked", false);
         q.hide();
     }
     else {
         c.prop("checked", true);
         q.show();
     }
});

$("#pagination_container").on("click", "label", function() {
     var c = $("#article_"+$(this).attr("data-pk"));
     var q = $("#qtecmd_"+$(this).attr("data-pk"));
     if (c.is(":checked")) {
         c.prop("checked", false);
         q.hide();
     }
     else {
         c.prop("checked", true);
         q.show();
     }
});
```

As you can see they do the same thing. So is it possible to combine these two handlers into a unique one to select both `".image-container"` and `"label"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comma separated

```
$("#pagination_container").on("click", ".image-container, label", function() {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any valid selector to `on()`, so here you can just pass a [multiple-selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector) which selects both the target elements like

```
$("#pagination_container").on("click", ".image-container, label", function() {
     var c = $("#article_"+$(this).attr("data-pk"));
     var q = $("#qtecmd_"+$(this).attr("data-pk"));
     if (c.is(":checked")) {
         c.prop("checked", false);
         q.hide();
     }
     else {
         c.prop("checked", true);
         q.show();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by separating it by comma. Have a look :

```
$("#pagination_container").on("click", ".image-container,label", function() {
  //your js code
});
```